# I can't connect VirtualIP pacemaker SQL Server cluster by user domain Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, ssms, cluster-computing, rhel, pacemaker

I can't connect VirtualIP pacemaker to SQL Server cluster by user domain Windows authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE4p2.png)

Now I can :

- Connect VirtualIP pacemaker SQL server cluster by Local admin user ex. sa account
- Connect primary node by user domain windows authentication and Local admin user

I installed SQL Server 2022 on RHEL8.

I need to suggestion some config for SSMS can connect VirtualIP Resource pacemaker by user domain windows authentication.

PS: sorry for the bad English. I need to suggestion some config for SSMS can connect VirtualIP Resource pacemaker by user domain windows authentication.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message on your screenshot clearly explains the cause of the issue. You are using Windows authentication when connecting, but your account comes from a different AD domain than the one the server is in, and there is no trust relationship defined between these two domains.

Your options are:

1. Ask your IT to establish the appropriate trust between the domains. They'll decide if it's okay (it probably isn't, but only they know that).
2. Use the account from the same domain the server belongs to. If you don't have one, ask your IT. However for this to work, you'll need to run SSMS under this account, and because there's no trust, Windows will probably refuse to do it. You might need to establish a RDP session with some box in the same domain the server is in (or the server itself) and run SSMS there. IT will probably refuse to give you such permissions, as it's quite a big risk.
3. Switch to SQL authentication. Again, you need to make sure that your SQL Server instance supports it (it can be turned off).